# Prove linear span $\langle C \rangle$ is smallest space containing $C$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

Let $C$ be a set of vectors in some vector space $V$ , and let $M$ be some subspace of $V$ . Show that if $C ⊆ M$ then $\langle C \rangle ⊆ M.$

I'm not really sure how to prove this. I think the point if this proof is to show that $\langle C \rangle$ is the smallest subspace containing $C$.

This was just for a proposition given, and I was just wondering how it can be proved. Thanks!

Comment: The way you show inclusion $A \subset B$ in math is to show that an arbitrary element of $A$ must be an element of $B$. So take an arbitrary element of the span of $C$, and show, using that $C \subset M$ and that $M$ is a subspace, that that vector must be in $M$.

Comment: @Joe so I just show that some $x$ from the span of $C$ is also in $M$? Does that prove that the span is the smallest subspace containing $C$?

Comment: Well, technically ***that*** doesn't prove that the span of $C$ is a subspace, but it does prove what you were asked to show, which combined with the fact that the span of $C$ ***is*** a subspace, does mean that it is the smallest...

Comment: @Joe do I need to prove that $C$ is subspace and so is its span for showing its the smallest? Because it's said that $C$ is just set of vectors, not a subspace. How can I show $C$ is subspace?

Comment: You posted question doesn't say that you need to show that the span of $C$ is a subspace; only that it is contained in $M$.

Answer (score 0):

Subspaces are closed under addition and scalar multiplication since they are vector spaces. By induction, subspaces are closed under linear combinations. Hence if $C \subset M$, then all linear combinations of elements of $C$ are in $M$, i.e. $\text{span}(C) \subset M$.